# R: Find out list of boundary coordinates

Tags: r

Suppose I have this map for the boundaries of North Carolina (USA) in R:

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# built in shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
    st_cast('POLYGON')

nc <- nc[nc$NAME %in% c("Cleveland", "Gaston", "Rutherford", "Burke"), ]    

leaflet(data = nc) %>% addPolygons( stroke = FALSE) %>% addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%  addProviderTiles(provider = providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% addPolygons(data = nc, weight=1, popup = ~NAME, label = ~NAME, group = "name", col = 'blue')
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to find out the list of coordinates that describe the exterior of this polygon (i.e. in "red"):

[image]

I tried the following code for this:

```
# Extract the boundary of the nc object
nc_boundary <- st_boundary(nc)

# Get the coordinates of the boundary
nc_boundary_coords <- data.frame(st_coordinates(nc_boundary))
```

However, when I tried to plot this - I can see that the plot doesn't correspond to the exterior boundary, but also contains intersections:

```
 plot(nc_boundary_coords$X, nc_boundary_coords$Y)
```

[image]

I thought I might be able to fix this by only taking the removing all instances of duplicates - but this still does not work:

```
df = data.frame(nc_boundary_coords$X, nc_boundary_coords$Y)

df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

But nothing changes.

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the selected counties into a single geometry using `st_union()`:

```
library(sf)

nc_boundary_coords <- nc %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_boundary() %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  data.frame()

plot(nc_boundary_coords$X, nc_boundary_coords$Y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
The difference is that I created a union first. The plot you showed looks like it has the boundaries for both internal and external borders.

```
nc_coords <- st_union(nc) %>% 
              st_boundary() %>% 
              st_coordinates() %>% 
               as.data.frame()

plot(nc_coords$X, nc_coords$Y)
```

[image: boundary points]